# Gradle Cannot have abstract method

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm developing a custom binary Gradle plugin, following the pattern shown [here](https://docs.gradle.org/6.8.1/userguide/implementing_gradle_plugins.html#capturing_user_input_to_configure_plugin_runtime_behavior).

My extension, VersionInfoExtension is abstract with abstract methods, just like the BinaryRepositoryExtension in the documentation. My task is also abstract, with abstract methods for the parameters, like the LatestArtifactVersion in the documentation. When I test, I get the following error:

```
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.example.version-info']
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.example.version-info'.
   > Could not create an instance of type com.example.gradle.version.VersionInfoExtension.
      > Could not generate a decorated class for type VersionInfoExtension.
         > Cannot have abstract method VersionInfoExtension.jars().
```

What am I missing? Are there any good examples of making this work?

Comment: Your Extension might not be configured by the time it is being used, which may mean it is being used in the apply method. You need to be sure that any extension values are used within tasks, not as a result of apply. Documentation is not overtly clear about this. You can use an init block in your class to help with default values

Comment: @BenjaminCharais, are you able to elaborate upon your point above? I'm encountering the same issue with a plugin and extension I have developed!

Answer (score 9):

I'm using gradle 7.X and Kotlin.

The "Cannot have abstract method myPropertyName" error is reported when the method name is prefixed by `"is"`:

```
abstract val isRegistered: Property<Boolean>
```

That was annoying to track down.  The type doesn't seem to matter.

The solution was to remove `"is"` from the name.

Comment: I had a similar issue, not because of the `is` prefix, but because of the variable name which might be reserved I assume. For example I had property named `name`. Changing it to `myName` solved the issue. My recommendation is to check if changing the name of the property fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here seems to be the name of the abstract method.

All configurable methods must be bean-methods - this holds for both Extensions and Tasks.

So you should have used (assuming a java class):

```
 abstract Property<String> getJars()
```

instead of

```
 abstract Property<String> jars()
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Richard Sitze answer, in my case it was a custom setter function that was used in tests only (annotated with `@TestOnly`) was preventing generating the class.

I had declared serializable object as `@Input`

```kotlin
@get:Input 
abstract val myPropertry : Property<MyObject>

@Test
fun setMyProperty(obj : MyObject){
   //...
}
```

Somehow the name of the function interfered with generating the property setter along generation of the setter.